# where is the method add for cart class in opencart

Tags: oop, e-commerce, opencart

I'm developing an integration on a opencart site with an hardcoded solution for calculate a cost of a product according to some input like height width and quantity and other some hidden value.

so

I'm trying to edit the add action for the cart to manage the sub-total in this specific circustance.

so I find in /catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php the this method:

```
$this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $this->request->post['quantity'], $option);
```

This action is in both of the cart controller page, index and update, but where is it the "add" method?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the method in

```
/system/library/cart.php
```

Be sure to make backups before editing, as its a core file

Comment: haha yes, that is something that could be used, but obviously not everyone wants to use it :)

Comment: Thanks! that saved hours of searching